# How can I improvise battle encounters on the fly?

Tags: savage-worlds, encounter-design

As of late, I've been very busy with college now that my schedule forces me to stay pretty much all day long, so I've had to stick with "low prep" games like Savage Worlds, and improvise adventures on the fly.

Picking what creatures to use, add new ones and creating environments on he run isn't an easy task, and I often end up making too messy or too easy combats, or drawing maps I don't really know how to use within the encounter.

Comment: How is the virtual tabletop influencing your inability to provide interesting encounters? Why is it relevant?

Comment: Because in my opinion, it's more time consuming to browse and upload creature tokens and draw battle maps using your mouse.

Comment: What kind of encounters?

Answer (score 3):

If this is just for encounters, try making tables of enemies, locations, environmental objects, etc. Then assign values to each and roll out the encounters an hour before play.

Also for enemies, make sure that you simplify their stats if they are common enemies. This can be done by limiting or removing certain dice rolls or through other methods.

It will give you a challenge to fit the encounter in with the story as well.